# DNS Resolver White List and block all other domains

Tags: domain-name-system, whitelist

A customer asked us to put on a DNS Resolver for its network.

What he requests is:
A list of allowed domains (white list) that the dns resolver can answer (anche cache)
Any other domains outside the whitelist must return a invalid dns record.

This is to allow access from his network to only few domains and block any other domains.

What software can i use? I have see powerdns recursor can be used with lua scripts but before try this way i ask if there is something already cooked...

Thank you
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BIND or linux beacuse is free and open source or you can use DNS server on Widnwos server 2003/2008.

You must configure manual zone which you want to serve clients. You must to delete root hints servers from config.

Comment: Thank you, but: suppose i want to use bind, how can i keep zone updated?. For example, I want to enable sites like gmail.com, how can i set up a manual zone for it and keep it updated?

Comment: Maybe you can use stub zone ?